# UITableViewCell rounded corner issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sdk

[image]

I want to make the last `UITableViewCell` bottom corners circular, I am able to do it, but it results that the boundary is not properly drawed, anyone have same experience with such type of issue, please help me. thanks

```
cell.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 8)
cell.clipsToBounds = true
cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.layoutSubviews()
```

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
        if numberOfRows - 1 == indexPath.row {
            cell.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 8)
            cell.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }

Comment: Calling it in willDisplayCell, let me know, if you have any suggestion

Comment: Have you provided border color and width for the same?

Comment: if I will provide border color, I have to set border width, in this case all four border of the cell get coloured and look weird because , I am using separator for uitableview

Comment: If you are not providing border color how you would expect it to fill?

Comment: I already let you know the issue that I faced while filling the border color, is there any other solution.

Comment: you can add round corner image (just the arc) at both the bottom corners of last cell

Answer (score 1):

Use UIBezierPath for rounding corner to last cell

```
    let totalRow : Int = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
    //first get total rows in that section by current indexPath.
    if indexPath.row == totalRow - 1 {
        //this is the last row in section.

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft,.bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
        cell.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }else{

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)).cgPath
        cell.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
```

Comment: let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
I am still using the same.

Answer (score 0):

then instead of cell you can make ur tableview round cornered.

Comment: but it has multiple sections, so for tableview it will not work

Comment: so for this situation you can make table footer view round corner

Comment: but I am already using separator , in case of footer view , it looks separate from last cell

Answer (score 0):

use `contentView`  and add your code at `willDisplay`

```
extension UIView {

    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }

}
```

Your Cell

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            cell.contentView.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 8)
            cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.contentView.layoutSubviews()
        }
```

Comment: you need last cell in tableView or tableview its self

Comment: I need last cell to be bottom rounded corners , for every section in tableview

Comment: This is the method     func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }